# AnyOf validation in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use simple input validation in **rating field** with AnyOf validation, but does not work!!
Can you please help me with this?? I want the user to enter a number that must be from 1-5 only.
Thank you guys!

class AddreviewForm(FlaskForm):

```
rating= StringField('Rating (1-5)',[validators.AnyOf(values=['1','2','3','4','5'])])
review_text=TextAreaField('Your Review', validators=[DataRequired()])
submit = SubmitField('Add review!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try without quotes and check the [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/)

```
validators.AnyOf(values=[1,2,3,4,5])])
```